# Using same disposable object twice in diffrent using-statment

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, idisposable, using-statement

I have made a disposable class UnitOfWOrk which will also acts as an optional parameter, I have provided an exampel below.

```
public async Task CallPersistItemPassUoW()
{
    using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(_connectionString, openTransaction: true))
    {
        try
        {
            await PersistItem(25, unitOfWork);
            unitOfWork.Transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            unitOfWork.Transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
}

public async Task CallPersistItem()
{
    await PersistItem(30);
}

public static async Task PersistItem(int itemId, UnitOfWork ouw = null)
{
    using (var unitOfWork = ouw ?? new UnitOfWork(_connectionString))
    {
        await unitOfWork.Connection.ExecuteScalarAsync(
            "insert into [dbo].[ItemTable](ItemId) values(@ItemId)",
            new
            {
                ItemId = itemId
            },
            unitOfWork.Transaction);
    }
}
```

As you can see both the methods CallPersistItemPassUoW and CallPersistItem calls the method PersistItem. CallPersistItemPassUoW passes a used UnitOfWork while CallPersisItem doesn't pass anything. If the parameter ouw (in the method PersistItem) doesn't have a value a new instance of UnitofWork is used in the using-statment otherwise the parameter is used in the using-stamtent. This means that the same UnitOfWork instance could be used twice, is that a problem in this case? If CallPersistItemPassUoW would call PersistItem would the instance of UnitOfWork be dispoced in CallPersistItemPassUoW  or in PersistItem?

Thank you!

Comment: Calling dispose twice is (in most cases) fine. The bigger problem is that `PersistItem` will dispose `ouw` if one is passed. So in the above method where you call `unitOfWork.Transaction.Commit();` afterwards, it would fail as `unitOfWork` has been disposed.

Comment: When dealing with `IDisposable`, there should be _clear ownership_ of the object, and only the _owner_ of the object should dispose the object. In your example above, you need to change `PersistItem()` so that it only disposes the object when the argument passed was `null` and it had to create it itself. Consider changing the method so that it doesn't _ever_ create the object; instead, push that requirement back to all callers, so there's always clear ownership and so that the `PersistItem()` code remains simple.

Comment: I'd recommend not to do that as this can get ugly pretty soon. By reusing the same instance of UOW that in this case is created elsewhere you break the Single Responsibility principle and this is code smell. It is better to either create an instance, use it and dispose it right away or to use dependency injection and [inject the instance with the scope](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dependency-injection-service-lifetimes/) for it that better suits your needs.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answers, they where all helpful and I have a clear plan on what I have to do.